# wine is not opening battlefront 2

Tags: wine

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

I've downloaded wine and wine Q4 and I've made sure that i have all the components for wine. I'm trying to play battlefront 2 (it's an exe file which I downloaded online). I have the original cd but I can't play in on my laptop as my disk drive is broken.

When I try to open the file with wine it acts as if it's about to open but then closes down and changes my screen resolution. I know the file works because I've used it before on windows 7.

The file also has .dll and .bink.32 which I think it needs to run.

How can I get it working?

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 0):

According to [Star Wars - Battlefront II WineHQ page](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=3803) only the "Steam 1.1" version really works (Platinum).

Keep this in mind for future reference: Anything below "Gold" is probably a waste of time. Software may install but then don't run or run partially and may have several other issues and limitations.

In conclusion, an Wine emulated `Star Wars - Battleship II` is doable if, and only if, it's running through Steam (for Windows). Any other installer gives mixed results and should be expected not to work.

Comment: okay so is steam a program ?

Comment: You call yourself a gamer and you never heard of Steam? http://store.steampowered.com/  It has TONS of NATIVE Linux games!

Comment: haha im not a gamer just like to play old classics from time to time thanks for the help

Comment: sorry about this but are you saying i have to buy the game again on steam? or does steam have another version of wine?

Comment: I'm merely stating facts in order to, hopefully, help you understand and have realistic expectations. What you do or don't it's up to you. If I were you, I would just dual boot Windows and run the one you already have there. Fortunately ALL the games I care about have native Linux versions already.

Answer (score -1):

Go to folder containing the game. There is a folder `GameData`. And inside is `BattlefrontII.exe`. Open it.